# MediatR publish and MediatR send

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, mediatr

I have tried the CQRS pattern using MediatR and am loving the clean state in which applications am working on are transforming.
In all the examples i have seen and used, I always do

```
await Mediator.Send(command);
```

It's been same for the queries as well

```
var data = await Mediator.Send(queryObject);
```

I just  realized there's Mediator.Publish as well which after searching seems to me to be doing the same thing. I am trying to understand what the difference between the Mediator.Send and Mediator.Publish is.
I have read the MediatR library docs and I still don't understand what the difference between these are.
Kindly help me understand the difference.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think "Send" method is for sending commands and it gives the response but "Publish" method is for sending events and doesn't return any response.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> MediatR has two kinds of messages it dispatches:
>
> - Request/response messages, dispatched to a single handler
> - Notification messages, dispatched to multiple handlers

- `Send` may return a response, but do not have to do it.
- `Publish` never return the result.

You are sending requests (sometimes called *commands*) by `_mediator.Send({command})` to exactly one concrete handler. It may be e.g. command that saves a new product to the database. It is often a request from the user (frontend/API) or sometimes it may be internal command in your system given by other *service* in a synchronous way. It is always expected that the command will be executed immediately and you will receive some proper result or error to immediately inform the client about some failures.

You are publishing notifications (often called events) by `_mediator.Publish({event})` to zero, one or many handlers. You used notifications when you want to publish some information and you do not know who needs that. E.g. `NewProductEvent` which is published after successfully adding product to your *Warehouse Module*. Few other contexts want to subscribe the information and e.g. send email to a client that a new product is available or create some default configuration for the product in your *Store Module* (which payment and delivery are available for the product). You may use notifications in a synchronous way. All data will be saved in one transaction (product and store configuration) or you may use some async pattern with *service bus* or/and *[sagas](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html)*. In the second case (asynchronous) you must manually handle cases when something wrong happens in other services or contexts which subscribe to your notification.

**Example scenario:** Default configuration was not created.

- If you have one transaction (synchronous way) for a few contexts, you will receive an error, log the error and return it to the user/client.
- In an asynchronous way, you send events after saving a new product to the database. You do not want to have the product in a half-error state in your system. So firstly I recommend creating it in the Draft state and wait for an event that informs you about the successfully created configuration and then changes the state to e.g New/Correct etc.

A good example of using mediatR you will find in e.g. Ordering microservice in [EShopOnContainers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/) by Microsoft: [github](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers). You will see an example usage of [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) and [DDD](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainDrivenDesign.html) with EF core and ASP Net.

Comment: Great, thank you for this explanation. So that means the Publish will be for Domain events?

Comment: yes but it could be also Application/Integration events at all. Example of integration mediatR with event bus is in EShopOnContainers

Answer (score 0):

**I will present code examples to explain. I won't use MediatR, but [IGet](https://github.com/dotnet-IGet/IGet), with which you can easily create MediatR-like functionality.**

In your startup class, instead of adding MediatR, use

```cs
serviceCollection.AddIGet();
```

**mediatR.Send**

Before sending a request you'll need to create a handler. The constructor may contain all kinds of dependencies, as long as they are part of your service collection.

```cs
public class WeatherForecastRequestHandler
{
    private IConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
    private ILogger<MyHandler> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastRequestHandler(
        IConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        ILogger<MyHandler> logger)
    {
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public WeatherForecast Handle(WeatherForecastRequest request)
    {
        // connect and get weather forecast

        return new WeatherForecast
        {
            // set properties.
        }
    }
}
```

Get the weather forecast:

```cs
var forecast = i.Get<WeatherForecastRequestHandler>().Handle(request);
```

**mediatR.Publish**

This example deviates more from how MediatR works internally, because MediatR collects all INotificationHandlers via assembly scanning. With [IGet](https://github.com/dotnet-IGet/IGet) you can also activate types from a `Type[]` but for now I will explicitly instantiate the handlers and invoke their methods. Let's do that in a class that we call `NotificationPublisher` (without logging exceptions in this example):

```cs
public class NotificationPublisher
{
    private IGet i;

    public NotificationPublisher(IGet iget)
    {
        i = iget;
    }

    public async Task PublishAsync(Notification notification)
    {
        try
        {
            await i.Get<FirstHandler>().HandleAsync(notification);
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            await i.Get<SecondHandler>().HandleAsync(notification);
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            i.Get<ThirdHandler>().Handle(notification);
        }
        catch { }
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Now define the 3 handlers in a similar way as in the first example and then we can publish a notification to all of them with one line of code:

```cs
await i.Get<NotificationPublisher>().PublishAsync(notification);
```

The [IGet readme](https://github.com/dotnet-IGet/IGet) actually also contains an example that shows how to make a generic notificaiton publisher for any type of notification.